# Multivariate normal distribution of regression coefficient?

Tags: multiple-regression

While reading a textbook on regression I encountered the following paragraph:

> The least squares estimate of a vector of linear regression coefficients ($\beta$) is
>
> $$ \hat{\beta} = (X^{t}X)^{-1}{X^t}y $$
>
> which, when viewed as a function of data $y$ (considering the predictors $X$ as constants), is a linear combination of the data. Using the Central Limit Theorem, it can be shown that the distribution of $\beta$ will be approximately multivariate normal if the sample size is large.

I'm definitely missing something from the text, but I don't understand how can a single $\beta$ value have a distribution? How are the multiple $\beta$ values generated to obtain the distribution referred to in the text?

Comment: $\beta$ is the vector of regression coefficients - does that clear up the confusion?

Comment: When using the least squares approach, you assume that $\beta$ is fixed but unknown. However, $\hat{\beta}$, since it's a function of the (random) data, has a distribution. Asymptotically the distribution is a normal distribution. Non-asymptotically, an individual coefficient will be a t distribution.

Comment: It may help to observe that $H = (X^tX)^{-1}X^t$ is considered a constant matrix in the regression setting and that $y$ is the realization of a (vector valued) random variable.  That bit about the CLT, though, is not quite correct: it is relying either on $H$ having a certain structure, which sometimes does not actually occur even with huge datasets, or else on $y$ itself being multivariate normal (but then there's no need to invoke the CLT).

Comment: @Taylor But how do you know the distribution of B if the only thing I know is that the "sample size is large" ?

Comment: @Taylor The individual component of the beta vactor will have a t distribution only if the error compoent in the regression model is Gaussian with 0 mean and constant variance.  In the non-normal case you wouldn't necessarily known its distribution under the null hypothesis but it may still be asymptotically normal. However as whuber states the central limit theorem may not hold because it is a weighted average and we need to know that the weights don't chnage with sample size in a way that allows a few terms to dominate the sum.

Comment: @Dbr As I just told Taylor you don't know that the estimator of beta has a t distribution unless you make the normality assumption.  So the answer to your question is that you don't knwo the distirbution knowing only the sample size.

Comment: @MichaelChernick I've never made inference about regressors without the normality assumption, so I can't really comment. Good point, though. And by the way, the hat matrix is $H = X(X^TX)^{-1}X^T$.

Comment: Could you add which textbook you got this information from? Thanks everyone for your comments on this I've learned a lot

Comment: I don't quiet get @whuber and Michael Chernick's comments on certain structure on $\left(X^t X\right)^{-1}X^t$. Are they about the limited spread conditions for CLTs?

Comment: @Paul The issue concerns how the model matrix $X$ behaves as the number of observations increases. When $X$ is a random variable there's no problem--just draw independent samples from its distribution--but what could it possibly mean for $X$ to be "constants" when rows are being adjoined to it? To even state a theorem, you would have to specify how those new observations are being created.  The results depend on that specification: if you're not careful, nothing in sight reaches any kind of limiting behavior.

Comment: @whuber I see. Thanks! Is it one of the reasons some textbooks are shifting from fixed predictors to random predictors, especially when the focus is on asymptotic analysis?

Comment: @Paul I haven't detected such a shift.  My impression has been that textbooks oriented towards observational disciplines, particularly economics, need to work with random regressors, while those oriented towards experimental disciplines tend to focus on the fixed-regressor formulation. You can do asymptotic analysis with fixed regressors: you just have to stipulate how their values are set asymptotically.  For instance, you can replicate a fixed set of values *ad infinitum*.

Comment: @whuber Thanks for the observation and explanation. My field is economics, maybe that's why I have this impression.

Comment: @whuber lecture notes I was going through argue that the coefficient estimators are multi-variate normally distributed rather than t, what's causing this discrepancy. Are they assuming asymptotic. See pg 21 A text I went through argued on pg 21 that the coefficients are multivariate normally distributed rather than t-distributed? What is causing the discrepancy here http://home.cc.umanitoba.ca/~godwinrt/4042/material/part3.pdf

Comment: @Wet You appear to be responding to an incorrect comment.  When $Y-X\beta$ has a Normal distribution (the usual assumption), then the formula for $\hat\beta$ gives it as an explicit linear combination of $Y.$ Thus, in either the fixed or random regressor formulations, $\hat\beta$ has a (multivariate) *Normal* distribution.  Student's t doesn't enter the picture until you start dividing estimates by their standard errors to test hypotheses.

Answer (score 4):

Not $\beta$ has a distribution but $\hat\beta$, as indicated by Taylor. The distribution of $\hat\beta$ stems from the fact that you get different $\hat\beta$ for different samples.---You can estimate this distribution based on the single $\hat\beta$ received from your single sample on condition that you have some information concerning the distribution of the underlying data.